# JavaScript 3 Dimensional String Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, canvas, multidimensional-array, 3d

I'm kind of stuck trying to do a 3 dimensional array.
Here's the code:

```
var text = new Array("purple", "red", "white");
text["purple", "red", "white"] = new Array("one", "two", "three");
text["purple", "red", "white"]["one", "two", "three"] = new Array(3);

var color = "white";
var font = "one";
var num = "two";

text[color][font][num]                  = new Image();
text[color][font][num]                  = "destination";
```

It doesn't run and when I inspect element it gives me a *"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'white' of undefined"* on the *text[color][font][num]                 = new Image();* line.

Please help, what am I doing wrong? :(

Comment: `text["purple", "red", "white"]` is incorrect and is equivalent to `text["white"]`

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `objects`, not `arrays`

```
var text = {
    purple: {
        one: new Array(3),
        two: new Array(3),
        three: new Array(3)
    },
    white: {
        //...
    },
    //...
}
```

Then you can access it like:

```
text['purple']['one'][0]
```

Or

```
text.purple.one[0]
```

Also, it seems to me, that following structure might be useful for you:

```
var text = {
    purple: {
        one: {
            image: new Image(),
            destination: "my destination"
        },
        // ...
    },
    // ...
}
```

Usage:

```
alert(text.purple.one.destination) //Will alert "my destination"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
text["purple", "red", "white"]
```

this is invalid.

After setting

```
var text = new Array("purple", "red", "white");
```

text, the array, can be accessed passing using the zero-based index of the item you are interested in.

```
text[0] // will be purple
text[1] // will be red
text[2] // will be white
```

Arrays as you can see can be accessed using their index, not by the value they hold. If you want to access a collection by value, use an plain object instead

```
var text = {
  "purple": {
    "one": {
      "one": null,
      "two": null,
      "three": null
    },
    "two": {
      "one": null,
      "two": null,
      "three": null
    },
    "three": {
      "one": null,
      "two": null,
      "three": null
    }
  },
  "red": {
    "one": {
      "one": null,
      "two": null,
      "three": null
    },
    "two": {
      "one": null,
      "two": null,
      "three": null
    },
    "three": {
      "one": null,
      "two": null,
      "three": null
    }
  },
  "white": {
    "one": {
      "one": null,
      "two": null,
      "three": null
    },
    "two": {
      "one": null,
      "two": null,
      "three": null
    },
    "three": {
      "one": null,
      "two": null,
      "three": null
    }
  }
}

var color = "white";
var font = "one";
var num = "two";

text[color][font][num]                  = new Image();
text[color][font][num]                  = "destination";  // you are overwriting here
```